# Received Bugdroid hat without using app

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app, winter-bash-2014

I got the Bugdroid hat last night on CodeGolf.SE. The thing is, I never used (or even downloaded) the Android app.

Did this happen to anyone else, or should I be worried that my account got hacked (in which case, why would anyone use the app then)? As far as I can tell, there wasn't any activity on my account at all in the relevant time frame.

If I'm the only one this happened to, could a dev look into which particular activity caused the hat to be given out?

Comment: You can always go to the web page of your OpenID provider (for SE it is https://openid.stackexchange.com/user) to see when someone logged on. That way you could check whether someone else logged on on your account.

Comment: @ProgramFOX Thanks, good idea. It doesn't look like there were any other logins.

Comment: The apps use the Stack Exchange API. Have you used any *other* application that uses the API, or the API itself? I don't know how the server marks API requests as *coming from the Android app*, but it is theoretically possible that an API access in your name was incorrectly detected as being an app request.

Comment: @MartijnPieters We've got a few Stack Snippets on code golf which use the API to generate leaderboards, but I don't think I used on of them last night (and even then, it would only have been a read access).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't have to worry, your account is under your sole control. Unfortunately when creating the query to find out who deserves a hat, I thought we recorded which app was used to *create* a comment, but we do in fact record which app *last touched* the comment. And in your case, a comment that you had posted was later deleted by a moderator (because it no longer applied), and *that moderator* was using the Android app.

I'm deploying a fix right now that prevents these cases from causing a hat award in the future, but unless you insist on it I'm not going to take the accidentally awarded hat away from you.

Comment: Hah, I actually noticed that said mod removed said comment. :D Thanks for clearing this up (and letting me keep the hat, because my Android version is actually too old to install the app ;)).

Comment: @MartinBüttner: I don't have an android device **at all**  yet I have the hat. (hint: modern PCs are perfectly capable of emulating other things). :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters - care to recommend a good emulator?

Comment: @Ste: I used Genymotion.

Comment: @MartijnPieters and for IOS

Comment: @Ankit: I use an iPhone for that...........